# Recording Audio in PyQt6 GUI using PyAudio

Tags: python, macos, microphone, pyqt6, macos-monterey

I want to make a PyQT6 app that will record audio for three seconds once a record button has been clicked. Currently I am trying to use PyAudio to record the audio but nothing seems to be working.

This is the code that I used:

```
import sys 
import wave 
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer 
import pyaudio 
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QWidget, QGridLayout

class RecordingWindow(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.init_ui() 
        self.chunk = 1024 
        self.sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16 
        self.channels = 1 
        self.fs = 44100 
        self.seconds = 3 
        self.filename = "new.wav" 
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Audio Recorder")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)

        self.status_label = QLabel("Press 'Record' to start recording.\nMicrophone will record for three seconds.", self)

        self.record_button = QPushButton("Record", self)
        self.record_button.clicked.connect(self.start_recording)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.status_label, 0, 0, 2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.record_button, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def start_recording(self):
        self.status_label.setText("Recording... Please Speak Loudly!")
        self.record_button.setEnabled(False)

        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.frames = []
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.sample_format,
                                  channels=self.channels,
                                  rate=self.fs,
                                  frames_per_buffer=self.chunk,
                                  input=True)

    # Start a QTimer to automatically stop recording after the specified duration
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.stop_recording())  
    # Use lambda to pass the instance
        self.timer.start(self.seconds * 1000)  # Convert seconds to milliseconds

    def stop_recording(self):
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
        self.p.terminate()

        wf = wave.open(self.filename, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(self.sample_format))
        wf.setframerate(self.fs)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
        wf.close()

        self.status_label.setText("Recording completed. Press 'Record' to record again.")
        self.record_button.setEnabled(True)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if hasattr(self, 'stream'):
            self.stream.stop_stream()
            self.stream.close()
            self.p.terminate()

        event.accept()
if __name__ == 'main': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    window = RecordingWindow() 
    window.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

However, when I run that code it won't record any audio. The window/app to record from and all of the buttons and text show up like they are supposed to. When I press the "Record" button it displays "Recording.... Please Speak Loudly!" like its supposed to but when I check my files the "new.wav" file says it has recorded for 0 seconds. I have looked all over the internet but haven't been able to find much that helps. If it helps, I am using macOs Monterey (Version 12.5), and I use VSCode to write the files, and I run the files using IDLE.

Comment: You are just opening the stream, that doesn't "record" anything: it's more or less like opening a file in python using `open()`: you have to *read* the data. You just created a `self.frame` list, but you never created any correlation with the stream that actually puts data there, so that list stays empty. See how the callback stream works in the [documentation](//people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/), but also consider using the QtMultimedia framework (see [QMediaRecorder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediarecorder.html) which should work fine for simple cases like this.